# Functions: Do you print inside or outside

Tags: python

just started on python and in function, I've seen people do it two different ways.

```
def test(x,y):
    z = x*y 
    print z 

test(4,6)
```

or

```
def test(x,y):
    return x*y  

z = test(4,6)
print (z)
```

I've tested it out and both give the same answer. Which way is more convenient or 'correct'? Is it better to print the statement inside the function and call the function or return the function to the caller and then assign a variable and print outside the function? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You mix Python 2 and Python 3 syntax - which do you use and why did you tag as Python 3?

Comment: What do you mean? Im using an online compiler for python but I've just started and assuming that this code is the same for python 2&3? Is it wrong?

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for the edit. I tried to indent it before posting but it didn't work well... Im watching a youtube guide for beginners and from it I've noticed some small issues like print needing () in 3 but not 2. Other than that they didn't specify any other differences? Could you explain?

Comment: `print` in python 2 works as in your above example, `print` in python 3 is a function that needs parenthesis'es. As for what you should use: python 3 and returning the values would be my preferred method. You _can_ print it that way, but you can also use it for other things. If you just print it - you dont have a 'multiply' function but a 'printMultResult' function. Beside that, 'test' is a bad name for a function, call it after what its designed to do - thats half the documentation you can do.

Comment: [Click here for explain](https://www.google.de/search?q=differences+between+python+2+and+3&rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE771DE771&oq=differences+between+python+2+and+3&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5831j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and then  [click here for why python 3 over 2](https://pythonclock.org/) explanation

Comment: Sorry for the issue, i forgot about it as the compiler i was using was python 2 (although the video I'm watching I'm guessing is for python3) Could you elaborate on what "you dont have a 'multiply' function but a 'printMultResult' function" means?

Comment: name functions after what they do. If you just print inside the function its a `def printResultOfMultOfNumers(x,y):` function - it will only ever print the result of x*y... If you return the value its a `def multiply(x,y):` function. You can use the latter for `print(multiply(2,5)` or `print(multiply(2,multiply(22,(multiply(8,9)))`.

Answer (score -1):

Print z is used prior to Python version 3.x.
Newer versions (>3.x) require the print() syntax. If you are defining a function for multiplication, you should not print inside of it, rather return the result and print it there: print(test(4,6)). In this way, you can also use the actual function for something else.

Comment: Thanks! In that case when do we use print inside the function?

Comment: Whenever you want to have that information inside the function :) It's a question of what the application should do. Like a function display_result() could print the result of your multiplication function:
def display_result(result):
    print(result)
Then call it with display_result(test(4,6))